# Google Drive API REST V2 insert file into folder file not found

Tags: java, file, google-drive-api, filenotfoundexception, file-not-found

I am trying to upload a file into one of my company's Google Drive folders but I haven't managed to achieve this without client intervention. So, whenever I use this:

```
package sample;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.ParentReference;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DriveCommandLine_srive
{

    private static String CLIENT_ID = "myClientID.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    private static String CLIENT_SECRET = "myClientSecret";

    private static String REDIRECT_URI = "mything";

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport( );
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory( );

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder( httpTransport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, Arrays.asList( DriveScopes.DRIVE ) ).setAccessType( "online" ).setApprovalPrompt( "auto" ).build( );

        System.out.println("xxxxx : "  + DriveScopes.DRIVE);

        String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl( ).setRedirectUri( REDIRECT_URI ).build( );
        System.out.println( "Please open the following URL in your browser then type the authorization code:" );
        System.out.println( "  " + url );
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
        String code = br.readLine( );

        GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest( code ).setRedirectUri( REDIRECT_URI ).execute( );
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential( ).setFromTokenResponse( response );

        // Create a new authorized API client
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder( httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential ).build( );

        insertFile(service, "Test File Drive", "This is a test file","myCompanysFolderID" , "text/plain", "./data/document.txt");

      }

    /**
     * Insert new file.
     *
     * @param service Drive API service instance.
     * @param title Title of the file to insert, including the extension.
     * @param description Description of the file to insert.
     * @param parentId Optional parent folder's ID.
     * @param mimeType MIME type of the file to insert.
     * @param filename Filename of the file to insert.
     * @return Inserted file metadata if successful, {@code null} otherwise.
     */
    private static File insertFile(Drive service, String title, String description,
        String parentId, String mimeType, String filename) {
      // File's metadata.
      File body = new File();
      body.setTitle(title);
      body.setDescription(description);
      body.setMimeType(mimeType);

      // Set the parent folder.
      if (parentId != null && parentId.length() > 0) {
        body.setParents(
            Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(parentId)));
      }

      // File's content.
      java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(filename);
      FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(mimeType, fileContent);
      try {
        File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();

        // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID.
        System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());

        return file;
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
        return null;
      }
    }

}
```

I manage to successfully upload the file to the company's folder, but I have to authorize it manually and paste the code each time. So, as I want to make this in an automatic way, I changed the authorization "method" to one that uses a service account p12 key to authorize the client. This is the new code after the change:

```
package sample;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.ParentReference;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class DriveCommandLine2
{

    private static final String KEY_FILE_LOCATION = "data/myp12Key.p12";
    **//Note: this is the mail from a service account in my dev console, it is different from the OAuth client I use in the previous method.**
    private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL ="myServiceAccountEmail@appspot.gserviceaccount.com";

    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
        "Drive API Java Quickstart";

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
        JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        //Drive service = getServiceManual();
        Drive service = initializeDrive();
        //insertFile(service, "Test File Drive", "This is a test file","myCompanyFolderID" , "text/plain", "./data/document.txt");
        insertFile(service, "Test File Drive", "This is a test file","" , "text/plain", "./data/document.txt");
      }

    /**
     * Insert new file.
     *
     * @param service Drive API service instance.
     * @param title Title of the file to insert, including the extension.
     * @param description Description of the file to insert.
     * @param parentId Optional parent folder's ID.
     * @param mimeType MIME type of the file to insert.
     * @param filename Filename of the file to insert.
     * @return Inserted file metadata if successful, {@code null} otherwise.
     */
    private static File insertFile(Drive service, String title, String description,
        String parentId, String mimeType, String filename) {
      // File's metadata.
      File body = new File();
      body.setTitle(title);
      body.setDescription(description);
      body.setMimeType(mimeType);

      // Set the parent folder.
      if (parentId != null && parentId.length() > 0) {
        body.setParents(
            Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(parentId)));
      }

      // File's content.
      java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(filename);
      FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(mimeType, fileContent);
      try {
        File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();

        // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID.
        System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());

        return file;
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
        return null;
      }
    }


    /////////////////////
    ///NEW GOOGLE ANALYTICS AUTH

    public static java.io.File convIs2File(InputStream inputStream, java.io.File file)
    {
        java.io.OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
            outputStream = new java.io.FileOutputStream(file);

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }

            System.out.println("Done!");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    // outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
        return file;
    }
    private static Drive initializeDrive() throws Exception {
        // Initializes an authorized analytics service object.

        // Construct a GoogleCredential object with the service account email
        // and p12 file downloaded from the developer console.
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        InputStream is = DriveCommandLine2.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
        java.io.File f = java.io.File.createTempFile("myP12Key", ".p12");
        java.io.File f_used = convIs2File(is,f);
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(f_used)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(DriveScopes.all())
                .build();

        // Construct the Analytics service object.
        return new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    }


}
```

But when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
An error occured: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "file",
    "locationType" : "other",
    "message" : "File not found: myCompanyFolderID",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "File not found: myCompanyFolderID"
}
```

So, my guess is that in the previous authorization way, I am using my Client_ID and Client_Secrets to authorize my app to insert things into my company's Drive space, so I find myCompanyFolder and I am able to insert the file successfully, however, in the second method, I am trying to insert the file into the service account Drive space that I am not able to access (**I know this because when I try to insert it in Drive's root, it works perfectly, however, I am not able to see the file in my root**).

So at the end, my question is, is there a way to insert the file into my company's drive folder without doing the manual authorization? That is, how do I authorize my app to upload the file in my company's drive without human interaction?

I think the client_secrets way won't work as I tried it before and it asks me to do it manually the first time I run the code. As I am running my code from a JAR file in a Linux server, this is not practical at all and doesn't work for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [`404: File not found`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#404_file_not_found_fileid) means that the user does not have read access to a file or the file does not exist.

Make sure that you provide the correct `access_token` when making the request for file metadata. Try to regenerate the authorization code, `access_token`. You need to [authorize and authenticate](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth) your requests on the behalf of the user, a key and your client ID will not be enough to access user's document.

The documentation suggest to report to users that they do not have read access to the file or that the file does not exist. Tell them that they should ask the owner for permission to the file.